# How to pass a value from the first view to fifth view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables

I know how to pass a variable from the first view to the second view by using the"PrepareForSeque" . But I would like to pass the variable to the fifth view and there is not any transition between the first and fifth view. Can you help me please?

Mina 
Best

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Personally, I would use a Singleton. Here is a tutorial about Singletons and other common design patterns in ios: http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can go with  NSUserDefaults by saving and retrieving data

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

or

> create on variable in AppDelegate and Access that value by sung
>   AppDelegate Object.

Comment: NSUserDefaults are for storing state over multiple executions of the app -- it's inefficient to use them in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the data through scenes using class methods.

**FirstViewController:**

In your .m file declare:

```
static NSInteger* staticScore;
```

Create class method and return this value:

```
+ (NSInteger*) passScore {
   return staticScore;
}
```

**In FifthViewController** `#import` this class and get value like this:

```
[FirstViewController passScore];
```